# Installing xlsx

Tags: python, excel

I used `pip install xlsx` in the **`cmd`**, but I faced this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlsx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlsx`
```

Comment: `xlsx` is a file extension, not a Python module (unlike `csv` which is both).

Answer (score 0):

There is no package called `xlsx` in python. Try `pip install pyexcel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use pip install pyexcel-xlsx